# One Dimensional Wave Equation with Piecewise Initial Conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

The problem I am trying to solve is:

$$ \begin{cases}
u_{tt} - c^{2} u_{xx} = 0 \\
u(x, 0) = g(x) \\
u_{t}(x,0) = h(x)
\end{cases}
$$

where $h(x) = 0$ and $g(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 \ : x < 0 \\
1 \ : x \geq 0
\end{cases}$

Via direct application of D'Alambert's formula, I arrived at the following solution:

$$u(x, t) =
\begin{cases}
0 \ : x - ct < 0\\
1/2 \ : \ x - ct < 0 < x + ct \\
1 \ : \ x - ct > 0
\end{cases}$$

where I plugged in $x - ct$ and $x + ct$ into $g$ and broke into cases depending on when it equalled $0$ or $1$.

My question is twofold. Firstly, I was hoping someone could confirm my answer. Secondly, to arrive at this answer I used the fact that $x - ct < x + ct$. Am I allowed to make this assumption; I noticed that the only time $c$ appears in the wave equation is as $c^2$. Can we make an assumption that $c > 0$ when solving the wave equation or is this not possible?

Comment: Since $c$ only appears in the $c^2$ term, I don't see why you couldn't assume $c > 0$.  Alternatively, you could just use $|c|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct, except for (what I'll assume to be) a typo in the first line: $u=0$ when $x+ct < 0$

You can also break it down like this

$$ u(x,t) = \begin{cases} 0, && x < -ct \\ \frac12, && -ct < x < ct \\ 1, && x > ct \end{cases} $$